OData Copernicus API single bands
I'm writing a python pipeline to download and process some S2 data and I am using the Copernicus API for the download part.
As I only need two bands (B04 and B08), I was wondering whether it's possible to filter my GET request to only return specific files, instead of downloading the entire product. That would save a lot of disk space and speed up my pipeline.
Currently my request hits the following url:
> https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/odata/v1/Products?$filter=Collection/Name
> eq '{data_collection}' and
> OData.CSC.Intersects(area=geography'SRID=4326;{polygon}') and
> ContentDate/Start gt {date_start_string}T00:00:00.000Z and
> ContentDate/Start lt
> {date_end_string}T00:00:00.000Z&$expand=Assets&$top=1000

I tried to include a name filter (e.g. and contains(Name, 'B04.jp2')) but I obtained an empty response.
Can you give me a hint?
